# Django form and formset are not valid

Tags: django

I'm trying to make a view containing one form and one formset but something does not work.
both form and formset after checking if .is_valid returns false. I do not really undersand why it is like that

```
def ProductCreateView(request):

    context = {}
    created_product = None
    form = ProductForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProductForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            created_product = form.save()
            print("Successfully created new product: {}".format(created_product))
        else:
            print("form is not valid")
            #print(request.POST) returns csrfmiddlewaretoken ...
            #print(request.FILES) returns file : inmemoryuploadedfile ...
            #print(list(request.POST.items()))
    context['form'] = form

    formset = ProductPhotoInlineFormset()
    if request.method=='POST':
        formset = ProductPhotoInlineFormset(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=created_product)
        if formset.is_valid():
            created_images = formset.save()
            print("Successfully created new imagest: {}".format(created_images))
        else:
            print("formset is not valid")
    context['formset'] = formset

    return render(request, "Ecommerce/create_product_test.html", context)
```

my template - create_product_test.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    <div id="alert-box">
        
    </div>

    <div id="image-box" class="mb-3">
        
    </div>
    <div id="image-box"></div>

    <div class="form-container">
        
        <button class="btn btn-primary mt-3 not-visible" id="confirm-btn">confirm</button>
        <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" id="image-form">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div>
                {{form}}
                
                {{formset.management_form}}
                {{formset.as_p}}
                
            </div>
        
            
        </form>
        
    </div>

    
{% endblock content %}
```

forms.py file

```
ProductPhotoInlineFormset = inlineformset_factory(
    Product,
    Photo,
    fields=('file',),
    form=PhotoForm,
    extra=1,

    )
```

where is the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find out what's wrong with the form with:

```
print(form.errors)
print(form.non_field_errors())
```

and for a formset:

```
print(formset.errors)
print(formset.non_form_errors())
```

This way, you can easily find out why the form is not valid.

Comment: I did as you set and I can see error for every single form field no matter if I fill them or not. - "This field is required".  is being displayed

Comment: What field is required? With "this field" i cannot do too much.\

Comment: Every single field of "Product" which is parent model in this case: name, category, availability, price

Comment: @KermitHQ can you print out every field missing with `form.instance.field_name`, this will tell you if the field is filled in the form instance.

Comment: I also can see "ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with. Missing fields: photo_set-TOTAL_FORMS, photo_set-INITIAL_FORMS. You may need to file a bug report if the issue persists." but it is also passed in template

Comment: @KermitHQ are you submitting it with javascript? What does `request.POST` print out to?

Comment: yes, by using ajax

Comment: @KermitHQ that makes me think not all form fields are being posted.

Comment: by printing out request.POST i'm getting <QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['MdG3Oo8NLoGcXXceoSDLs5WAjiH0Jam59FETQ4wBAESh4YoomVSeDzQIKzRUvJ2R']}>

Comment: I guess I found the cause of erorrs but i need few minutes to check it

Comment: You were right, the issue was missing data in JS